# Piechart not rotating on tap in Coreplot- iOS

Tags: core-animation, core-plot

Please refer to the code for rotating the piechart **when any sice is touched:**

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

[self rotatePieChart:plot];
```

}

```
-(void)rotatePieChart:(CPTPieChart *)plot {    

[CATransaction begin];
{
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-45, 0, 0, 1);
    rotation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
    rotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotation.duration = 1.0f;
    rotation.cumulative=YES;
    rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO; 

    [plot addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];

}
[CATransaction commit];

}
```

***ON first Tap the piechart rotates but on subsequent taps nothing happens.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rotating the whole plot layer, animate only the `startAngle` property. I suspect the hit-detection code is getting confused by the rotated coordinate system.

Comment: What is startAngle based on? I assumed 0-360º (with 0 being "west") but that doesn't appear to be correct.

Comment: It uses the standard polar coordinate system--angles are in radians with zero to the right (east).